# Module not loading unless bootstrapped

Tags: modules

I'm expanding my Craft website with a small Module, internal to this project. The module currently only defines a new input-field (extending `craft\base\Field`).

I have dumped the autoloader from composer and my `config/app.php` only contains the registration of this module:

```
<?php
return [
    'modules' => [
        'simple-markdown-editor' => [
            'class' => \codeisland\simplemde\MarkdownModule::class,
        ],
    ],
    'bootstrap' => ['simple-markdown-editor'],
];
```

This setup works and the new field shows up in the Admin CP. **But**: as far as I understand the `bootstrap`-entry, it's only needed if the module needs to be executed on *every page render*. The [Craft documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/module-guide.html#update-the-application-config) says as much:

> TIP: If your module doesn’t need to get loaded on every request, you can remove its ID from the bootstrap array.

Since the module only defines an input-field for the Admin CP, it doesn't need to be loaded on every request. But if I remove it from the `bootstrap`-array, it's not loaded at all.

Do I need to add additional config? Or am I just misunderstanding the documentation?

Comment: I’ve experienced this too. Curious to know if this is a bug, a documentation error, or if there is some legitimate workaround.

Answer (score 2):

It does in fact need to be loaded on every request, because otherwise your `EVENT_REGISTER_FIELD_TYPES` event listener wouldn’t get registered, which is responsible for telling Craft that the field type exists.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks for the feedback. Is there a rule of thumb on when it's save to not put the module in the `bootstrap`-array?

Comment: Yeah, when your module isn’t doing anything special in `init()`.

Comment: "special" meaning not registering anything via `Event`?

Comment: That’s one example, yes.